# Default username and password for LUCI2

Tags: openwrt, luci

I uploaded the LUCI2 from Git to my OpenWrt box. For the first access to the web interface we must input login name and password. What should these two parameters be?

I typed admin/admin, and they did not work. Even if I execute the command: 'passwd admin' and I add 'admin' as new passwd.

Comment: Please add more info about your problem. Describe what you want and what  not work as expect.

Comment: I uploaded th LUCI2 from git to my OpenWRT. And to access too the interface I get a login frame. I typed admin/admin and does not work. Even if I execute the command: 'passwd admin' and I add 'admin' as new passwd